# Add a message to messages array using theme process or preprocess function

Tags: theming, status-messages

For testing purposes, I'm trying to manually add a message to the `$messages` array, in either process or preprocess page function. To be clear, I first tried using

```
template.php -> mytheme_preprocess_page (&$vars) {}
```

but then I realized there's no `$messages` array there, so instead I am doing it via **process.page.inc**.

The code I have tried, which is not working is:

```
function mytheme_process_page(&$variables) {
    $variables[messages][] = 'new test message';
    kpr($variables);  
}
```

I have tried some variations on this, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$messages` isn't an array of messages; it's the rendered output of [`theme_status_messages()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7). From the point at which you're looking to add messages (template_process_page()), Drupal has already processed all the messages it's going to render.

If you're looking to print some debugging messages you can do something like this:

```
function MYTHEME_process_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_set_message('new test message');

  //This will overwrite any previous messages that were to be rendered
  $variables['messages'] = theme_status_messages(array('display' => null));
}
```